# Convert multidimensional JSON to multidimensional JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I receive from the server a JSON like the following:

```
{"sent":{"Executive":1},"received":{"Executive":1},"viewed":{"Executive":1}}
```

how to convert this structure to a JavaScript multidimensional array?

I would want something like this:

```
var sent = [["Executive", 1]];

var received = [["Executive", 1]];

var viewed = [["Executive", 1]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most dynamic way surely is a good old `for`-loop.
Javascript doesn't ship with built-ins making this task easier.

An example of a 1d-array. I leave it open to the thread creator to add another, inner for-loop.

```
var json_data = {"sent": 1, "received": 2};
var result = [];

for(var i in json_data)
    result.push([i, json_data [i]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var plotdata = []; 
            var scale = [];
            var color = new Array();
            color[0] = "#3983C2";
            color[1] = "#F79263";
            color[2] = "#CB6FD7";
            color[3] = "#87B87F";
            color[4] = "#9ABC32";
            color[5] = "#D53F40";
            color[6] = "#999999";

            var x = 0;
            for(var i in json_data) {       
                var obj = json_data[i];
                var d1 = [];            
                for(var k in obj) {
                    d1.push([k, obj [k]]);  
                    scale.push([obj [k]]);      
                }
                x++;
                plotdata.push({ color: color[x], label: i, data: d1});
            }
```

Comment: If you are answering your own question, then please provide a proper **explanation** at least, don't just post code. At first glance, the code has nothing to do with the code in the question.